# Prototype Constructor Call

Tags: javascript

Instead of using the call method, would it be applicable to utilize the following, e.g:

```
var A = function(height,weight) {
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
};

var a = new A("6ft","500lbs");

A.prototype.foo = {
    setup: function() {
        this.height.set();
        this.weight();
    },

    height: {
        set: function() {
            var constr = a;
            var self = this;

            console.log(constr);
            console.log(self);
        }
    },

    weight: function() {
        var constr = a;
        var self = this;

        (function() {
            console.log(constr);
        })();
    }
};

a.foo.setup();
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The ability to inherit properties from the constructor when I need them without using the call/apply method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, but what a mess.  `height` and `weight` have two different meanings; all instances of `A` will refer back to that initial `a`.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?

**Edit:**

The problem with using prototypes is that, when one is created, there is no functional context specific to an instance (for the obvious reason that the prototype is only created once, typically before any instance of the class.  Without a context, there's no place to stash variables private to the instance.  What I prefer is to create methods at construction:

```
var A = function(height, weight) {
    this.height = function() { return height; };
    this.weight = function() { return weight; };
};
```

Use a function to create the prototype itself creates a common (private, static) context for *all* instances.  You can even mix the concepts:

```
var A = function(height, weight) {
    this.__init__(height, weight);
};

A.prototype.__init__ = (function() {
   // any variables declared here are private and static
   var number_of_instances = 0;
   return function(height, weight) {
      // any variables declared here are private and NOT static

      // as always, anything added to this are public and not static
      this.getNumberOfInstances = function() {
          return number_of_instances;
      };

      this.height = function() { return height; };
      this.weight = function() { return weight; };
      number_of_instances++;
   };
})();
```

I'm not thrilled about over-writing the *entire* prototype, that means you couldn't change A to inherit from another class.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the ability to call the constructor properties when I need to do so. Additionally, I want the ability to have public/private scopes. The aforementioned code block is a more of a stress test.

Comment: Thanks, Your example works nicely! I do have two questions left: http://pastie.org/1418410 - In regards to placements of var a = new A(); where is the preferred placement, e.g: right after the constructor function, or lower down in the file? Also, from the examples in the pastie, which one is the better out of the bunch?

Comment: In general, the code defining class is kept with the code defining related classes, so as to form a logical module or library.  The constructor is called -- that is, an instance is instantiated -- wherever it is need, which is often quite far away, usually in different files altogether.  The examples in pastie are all kind of odd, in subtly different ways.  I think you should design a nice neat API first, and then write the code to match it.  BTW, a bit of StackOverflow etiquette: if you like my answer, star or upvote it.